# Add coefficients of a vector to a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I would like to add each coefficient of a vector to each different column of a matrix. For example, if I have a vector and a matrix:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
M <- matrix(c(5,6,7), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

I would like to in my new matrix `M1` 1+5 in the first column, 2+6 in the second and 3+7 in the last one.

Is there any function in R that does this task?

Comment: I think your description is not correct as in `M`, the first row is `5`, 2nd as `6` and 3rd as 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
M + rep(x, each = nrow(M))
```

or this:

```
apply(M, 1, `+`, x)
```

result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    6    7    8
[2,]    7    8    9
[3,]    8    9   10
```

EDIT:
akrun commented on two other great solutions:

```
M + x[col(M)]
```

and

```
sweep(M, 2, x, "+")
```

Comment: Or it could be shortened `M+x[col(M)]` or `sweep(M, 2, x, '+')`